# Connect Flask app to SQL Server using Flask-SQLAlchemy with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085353/12636797) to setup with Windows authentication. Don't know if it works as there is an error right now.

Right now I have this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')
app.config['SQLACHLEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql://LAPTOP-GNBBOVKT/SQLEXPRESS/OIS?trusted_connection=yes'
db = sqlalchemy(app)

class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = db.Column('Country_ID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column('Country_Code', db.String)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    allCountries = Country.query.all()
    return jsonify(allCountries)
```

But I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`at`db = sqlalchemy(app)

EDIT: Fixed the error by changing sqlalchemy to SQLAlchemy but now I'm getting

```
UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
```

Probably because it's not connected to the database.

EDIT: What finally fixed it was importing pyodbc and changing URI line:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + 'LAPTOP-GNBBOVKT\\SQLEXPRESS' + '/' + 'OIS' + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'
```

Comment: Are you using a username and password.

Comment: I want it to work with Windows Authentication as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085353/12636797

Comment: On the post you have mentioned check the comment by DoloMike on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise the db object by `db = SQLAlchemy ()`

Also change your import to `from flask_sqlaclhemy import SQLAlchemy`

Edit:
There is a typo 
Change to `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`
There's a typo

Comment: That fixed, the error, but the URI still seems to be wrong.

Comment: Edited answer. Pls check

Comment: Fixed the typo now I'm getting `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) `

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use mssql. I am check the issue out

Comment: The data right now exists in an mssql db which is updated daily, so it's not up to me to chose the database.