# Write Pandas dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pandas

I have SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2000.8) and I want to auto update a table via panda dataframe.

As I understood, it can be done from sqlalchemy and looks something like this:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>")
```

Server is on my local machine and I have windows authentication (Windows 10 to be precise).

Can someone advice me which string should be used in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer on following page (similar question) :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085352/how-do-i-connect-to-sql-server-via-sqlalchemy-using-windows-authentication][1]
and string looks something like this:

```
sqlcon = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + 'server_name' + '/' + 'db_name' + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')
```

After that we can use dataframe.tosql method to import from panda to MS SQL database.