# Error Connecting to SQL Server database using Sqlalchemy module in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am stuck connecting to my database. I'm not sure why the error as follows keep coming out even though I've followed the documentation clearly.

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My connection string looks like this

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from sqlalchemy import desc, create_engine

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc://localhost\SQLEXPRESS/master?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=True'
app.config['SQLALCEHMY_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    author = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, title, description, author):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.author = author


class PostSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("title", "description", "author")


post_schema = PostSchema()
posts_schema = PostSchema(many=True)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_post():
    return jsonify({"Hello": "World"})


@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
    title = request.json['title']
    description = request.json['description']
    author = request.json['author']

    my_post = Post(title, description, author)
    db.session.add(my_post)
    db.session.commit()

    return post_schema.jsonify(my_post)


db.init_app(app)
ma.init_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Is there anywhere in which I left out? Whenever I tried to create a post request through postman, it will show the error as stated above. I am sure the ODBC driver exist and I've connected it to the local database that I have installed in my PC. Also, table Post is already created on my database such as follows:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Post]    Script Date: 23-Mar-22 1:30:52 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [author] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: looks like its trying to connect to `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and database `master`?  ... I dont think thats what you actually want ... at a minimum you need to escape the backslash I think `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: this looks relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085353/541038

Comment: yes that is the name of my server and database.. adding double backslash doesnt seems to solve the issue

Comment: In its [default configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration?view=sql-server-ver15#default-configuration) SQL Server Express edition isn't listening on either TCP/IP or Named Pipes protocols. Have you gone into SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager yet and enabled the TCP/IP protocol? You'll need to restart *both* the SQL Server service and the SQL Browser service after making changes here so that the Instance Name resolution of `\SQLEXPRESS` actually works.

Comment: You also have two `?` characters in your connection Uri.

Comment: ahhh I see. what a silly mistake that I've done. thank you very much for reviewing the URI

Answer (score 0):

As reviewed, The connection URI was missing escape of the backslash and '&' instead of '?' symbol. Thanks for the suggestions.