# Connection to MSSQL Server with {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} with AD system user fails

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect a windows system user in my SQLAlchemy framework with an MSSQL Server.
I'm developing on an Max M1 with FreeTDS Driver with the same user. To connect, I set the authentification to ["authentication"] = "ActiveDirectoryPassword" and everthing works like a charm. When I try to run the same code on a windows machine with ODBC Driver insead of FreeTDS (with a different user than the user with the database access, so I can't simply use the trusted_connection="yes" argument) the connection is refused because the username is deleted in the connection string.

```
InterfaceError('(pyodbc.InterfaceError) (\'28000\', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'\'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user \'\'. (18456)")')
```

I create my collection string like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

if "MacBook" in socket.gethostname():
    driver = "FreeTDS"
else:
    driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
self.db_api = "pyodbc"

query_dict = {
        "driver": driver,
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes", 
        "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryPassword" 
    }


connection_url = URL.create(
    f"mssql+{self.db_api}",
    username=self.user,
    password=self.password,
    host=self.server,
    port=self.port,
    database=self.database,
    query=query_dict,
)
self.engine = create_engine(connection_url)
con=Connection(self.engine)
```

On the mac I use Python 3.9.12 and SQLAlchemy==1.4.42.
On the windows machine is a
Edition Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎20/‎2022
OS build    20348.1487
with Python 3.9.2 and SQLAlchemy==1.4.42.

I tried changing the driver to "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" with the same outcome.
When setting the "TrustServerCertificate" to "no " I get another error:

```
OperationalError("(pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\\r\\n (-2146893019) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
```

I also tried disabling the Encryption and all the other authentifications provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16) without any effect.
Leaving authentification method blank:

```
 '28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxx\\xxxx'
```

Setting authentification method to "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated":

```
('FA002', "[FA002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated' with User or Password options.
```

Comment: what happens if you remove  "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryPassword"  on windows?

Comment: Or change it to ActiveDirectoryIntegrated

Comment: Event Viewer: check this on client machine and on server machine.

Comment: Client machine: execute sqlcmd -E -S <SQLInstance PleaseReplace>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58858572/18221995) answer!
Not sure if I stumbled upon a bug in the pyodbc package or what but changing the db_api to pymssql did the trick!
My connection string now is as follows:

```
if "MacBook" in socket.gethostname():
    driver = "FreeTDS"
    self.db_api = "pyodbc"
    query_dict = {
        "driver": driver,
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes", 
        "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryPassword" 
    }
else:
    driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
    self.db_api = "pymssql"
    query_dict = {
    }

connection_url = URL.create(
    f"mssql+{self.db_api}",
    username=self.user,
    password=self.password,
    host=self.server,
    port=self.port,
    database=self.database,
    query=query_dict,
)
```